# Time average of a given hourly period over months

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I was looking for finding  the average worker start time over a given period and returning the result within a scale of 00:00 to 24:00 hours.

Here are our data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
'ID_worker': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6],
'working_start_time': ['2010-01-01 12:01:00', '2010-01-01 01:27:33', 
'2010-04-02 12:01:00', '2010-04-01 07:24:00', '2011-01-01 12:01:00', 
'2011-01-01 01:27:33', '2013-01-01 12:01:00', '2014-01-01 12:01:00', 
'2014-01-01 01:27:33', '2015-01-01 01:27:33', '2016-01-01 01:27:33', 
'2011-01-01 01:28:00']})
```

After having got the result, I would like to plot them as: the time scope (00:00 till 24:00) as x-axis
and number of employee as y-axis. For example, there are 200,000 worker have same average starting time 8:34 am.
And the average start time of each worker in a column corresponding to their IDs.

I tried the following command:

```
data.groupby(by=['ID_worker', 'working_start_time'])['working_start_time'].mean().reset_index()
```

But unfortunately this method doesn't work.

Any help would nbe very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# convert dates to numeric representation
df['working_start_time_num'] = pd.to_numeric(pd.to_datetime(df.working_start_time))
# groupby ID_worker and calculate mean of working_start_time_num
start_time_means = df.groupby('ID_worker').working_start_time_num.mean()
#convert means to datetime
start_time_means = pd.to_datetime(start_time_means)
# drop temporary feature
df = df.drop(columns=['working_start_time_num'])
```